# Read variable length file into 2d char array

Tags: c++, arrays

Beginner student, trying to read input into a 2d char array. 
input file format is:     ,,,a,a,a,a,,, '\n' ,,,,,,,,,
Needs to be in a 10 by 10 array, will always have 9 commas and no spaces, that why i have my const int at twenty in case there is a "ship" placeholder taking up space  having issue reading in the characters and when i did get to read in it would skip every other character.
any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std; 
bool checkship();
string filename; 
ifstream inputfile;
int rowcount= 0, colscount=0;
const int rows=20, cols=20 ; 
char boardarray[rows][cols];

int main()
{
   cout<< "input your battlestation board filename: " << endl;
   cin >> filename;
   inputfile.open(filename.c_str()); 
   while(!inputfile)
   {
      cout << "file did not oipen please retry";
      cin >> filename;
      inputfile.open(filename.c_str());
   }

   while(inputfile)
   {
      for(rowcount=0;rowcount < rows;rowcount++)
      {
         for(colscount=0; colscount < cols; colscount++)
         {
            char ch;
            inputfile >> ch;

            while( ch!= '\n')
            {
               inputfile >>  boardarray[rowcount][colscount];
            }
            if(ch = '\n')
            { rowcount++;
               colscount= 0;
            }
         }                                                                                                                                                                     }  
   }
   inputfile.close();

   for(rowcount=0; rowcount <10 ; rowcount++)
   {
      for(colscount=0; colscount< cols; colscount++)
      {
         cout << boardarray[rowcount][colscount];
         if(colscount == 9)
            cout << endl;
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The contents of the files is not clear to me. `inputfile >>  boardarray[rowcount][colscount];` will be a problem if there are any whitespace characters in the file.

Comment: [You may find `std::getline` to be helpful in simplifying your logic.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

string filename;
ifstream inputfile;
int rowcount= 0, colscount=0;
const int max_rows=20, max_cols=20 ;
char boardarray[max_rows][max_cols];

int main()
{
   cout<< "input your battlestation board filename: " << endl;
   cin >> filename;
   inputfile.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
   while(!inputfile)
   {
      cout << "file did not oipen please retry";
      cin >> filename;
      inputfile.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
   }

   while(!inputfile.eof())
   {
        char ch = 0;
        colscount = 0;
        while( ch!= '\n' && !inputfile.eof())
        {
           inputfile.read(&ch, 1);
           if (ch != '\r' && ch!='\n') {
               if (ch != ',') {
                   boardarray[rowcount][colscount] = ch;
               } else {
                   colscount++;
               }
           }
        }
        rowcount++;
        colscount++;
   }
   inputfile.close();

   for(int i=0; i < rowcount; i++)
   {
      for(int j=0; j< colscount; j++)
      {
         cout << boardarray[i][j];
         if(j == (colscount-1))
            cout << endl;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, ill give this a shot. Been stuck on this problem for too long. @user3811082